# Setup a server for traffic monitoring using wireshark in bridge mode

Tags: wireshark, bandwidth, network

i was able to get a hold of a server with 2 ethernet ports to start learning about traffic inspection using wireshark.

The server and software are setup. I would like to know how i can configure the server to be in bridge mode.

My Modem is a 3g access point with ethernet ports at ip 192.168.1.1, pluggin in to an assus wifi/router at ip 192.168.2.1.

I would like to place my wireshark in between those 2 and see how much data is being consumed and by what device.

Can someone please guide me as to the steps to take?

Thanks.

Comment: It's much easier to set up a mirror port on your switch and have it mirror all frames from a source port into the Wireshark machine.

Comment: My ports are not manageable sadly, is there no other way to do? I understand the easy way, sadly i can't do it for now.

Comment: Questions about server configuration are off topic here. You can consider asking them on [su] for personal servers or on [sf] for enterprise servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you can use `bridge-utils`. With bridge-utils you can bridge two or several interfaces together.

First you have to have the devices on the same network so move assus wifi/router at ip 192.168.2.1 to for example 192.168.1.2

1. Install `sudo apt-get install bridge-utils`
2. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` so it will look like something like this

`iface eth0 inet manual`

`iface eth1 inet manual`

`# Bridge setup
 iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
        address 192.168.1.10
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1`

And then restart the network service `service networking restart`

This will bridge eth0 and eth1 into a bridge br0 and set the IP adr. on the br0 to 192.168.1.10 and blank the IP ad. on eth0 and eth1.

`+--------+    +--------------+    +--------+
 | 3G     |    |    Server    |    | ASUS   |
 | Modem  |    |              |    | wifi/  |
 |        |    |     br0      |    | router |
 +----+---+    +--+------+----+    +----+---+
      |       eth0|      |eth1          |
      |           |      |              |
       \----------       \---------------`

Comment: This is an example for Linux (Debian, Ubuntu), other distros have other configuration files but behaves the same.

Comment: I'm on windows, i will do research. I have a whole network behind i cannot change on 2.1 subnet. This is very kind, i will see how i can adapt this.

Comment: So by bridging as you showed though do i need to change anything on the router or modem? Those 2 still point to each other's Ip and they will not see the server in between them at the 2.10 ip address?

Comment: I think you have a error in your description regarding the IP adr.